# Email Not Sending after newsletter subscription

Tags: newsletter, magento1.9.3

I am using BigRock server for magento site. I set the smtp setting from `system->Mail Sending Setting`. and also create mail account on bigrock server.
but magento not sending any email.
log error : `Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail`
can any one help me for that.

`Host` : `name.domain.com`
`Port` : `25`.

My Magento Version :`1.9.3.4`.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because of your mail server misconfiguration issue. If you can't get it working you can use the SMTP module to send the magento email using gmail server or any other server.

You can find the module http://www.aschroder.com/product/smtppro-magento-smtp-email/. It's free and it works perfectly.

Hope this helps.